# How to define propTypes for a component wrapped with withRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, higher-order-components

I'm wondering what the best practices are for defining `propTypes` on a component that will be wrapped with a 3rd-party HOC, in this case, `withRouter()` from `React-Router`.

It is my understanding that the point of `propTypes` is so you (and other developers) know what props a component should expect, and React will give warnings if this is violated.

Therefore, since the props about location are already passed by `withRouter()` with no human intervention, is it necessary to worry about them here?

Here is the component I'm working with:

```
const Menu = ({ userId, ...routerProps}) => {

  const { pathname } = routerProps.location
  return (
      // Something using userID
      // Something using pathname
  )
}

Menu.propTypes = {
  userId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  // routerProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  // ^ this is undefined, bc withRouter passes it in later?
}

export default withRouter(Menu)

//.... in parent:
<Menu userId={id} />
```

What would be the convention in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is my understanding that the point of propTypes is so you (and other developers) know what props a component should expect, and React will give warnings if this is violated.

This is correct.

> What would be the convention in this case?

I don't think you will find a definitive answer to this.  Some will argue that if you define one `propType` you should define all expected prop types.  Others will say, as you did, that it wont be provided by the parent component (excluding the HOC) so why bother.  There's another category of people that will tell you not to worry with `propTypes` at all...

Personally, I fall into either the first or last category:

- If the component is for consumption by others, such as a common ui component (e.g. TextField, Button, etc.) or the interface for a library, then `propTypes` are a helpful, and you should define them all.
- If the component is only used for a specific purpose, in a single app, then it's usually fine to not worry about them at all as you'll spend more time maintaining them than debugging when the wrong props are passed (especially if you're writing small, easy to consume functional components).

The argument for including the `routerProps` would be to protect you against changes to the props provided by `withRouter` should they ever change in the future.

So assuming you want to include the `propTypes` for `withRouter` then we need to breakdown what they should actually be:

```
const Menu = ({ userId, ...routerProps}) => {
  const { pathname } = routerProps.location
  return (
      // Something using userID
      // Something using pathname
  )
}
```

Looking at the above snippet, you may think the `propTypes` should be

```
Menu.propTypes = {
  userId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  routerProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

But you'd be mistaken... Those first 2 lines pack in a lot of `props` transformation.  In fact, it should be

```
Menu.propTypes = {
  userId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  location: PropTypes.shape({
    pathname: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired
}
```

Why? The snippet is equivalent to:

```
const Menu = (props) => {
  const userId = props.userId
  const routerProps = Object.assign({}, props, { userId: undefined }
  const pathname = routerProps.location.pathname
  return (
      // Something using userID
      // Something using pathname
  )
}
```

As you can see, `routerProps` doesn't actually exist in the `props` at all. 
 `...routerProps` is a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) so it gets all the other values of the `props`, in this case, `location` (and maybe other things you don't care about).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I wasn't sure I'd be able to get both the normal props and the HOC props in there at once.